# Creating a list of objects belonging to another class using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Films class, that has a property of a list of screenings. I'm using two listboxes, one for the Films then one for the showings. I'm trying to read the films and the screenings in from a database, the relationship being that the FilmID is the foreign key in the screenings. I was wondering if it was possible to query the database so i'd create several Films objects with the screenings being added to the list of screenings in the films class. So the screenings that I have that have a FilmID of 3 for example will all go in the list of screenings in the films class that has the ID of 3 also

I've tried this, but i'm unsure as to where to go next. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var query = from f in db.Films
            join s in db.Showing__s
            on f.FilmID equals s.FilmID
            select new
                   {
                       fID = f.FilmID
                        FilmName = f.FilmName,
                        FilmDetails = f.FilmDetails,
                        ReleaseDate = f.Release_Date,
                        Rating = f.AgeRating,
                        ShowDate = s.ShowDate,
                        FilmID = s.FilmID
                    };
```

Comment: what is your db's class? Was it made using Linq-To-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your relationships are properly set up, you should just use the navigation properties.

But if you have to do it in a different way, you could try something like this:

```
from f in db.Films
select new
{
    film = f,
    screenings = from s in db.Screenings 
                 where s.FilmId == f.FilmId
                 select s
};
```